# nullpointer exception while deploying via kubernetes plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-plugins

We are using **Google kubernetes engine-plugin**- 0.8.1 for Jenkins for deploying an app via yaml files, strangely we are getting java exceptions while our app is developed using python.
following is the detailed error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.Manifests$ManifestObject.addLabel(Manifests.java:114)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubernetesEngineBuilder.addMetricsLabel(KubernetesEngineBuilder.java:303)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubernetesEngineBuilder.perform(KubernetesEngineBuilder.java:266)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please note that building Docker image step and pushing it to DockerHub worked flawlessly as declared it in the jenkinsfile, following is my Jenkinsfile where the deployment to kubernetes cluster is happening.

```
stage("Step 3: Deploy BUILT artifacts to K8"){
            steps{
                step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', projectId: env.PROJECT_ID, clusterName: env.CLUSTER_NAME, location: env.LOCATION, manifestPattern: 'configmap-staging.yaml', credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID, verifyDeployments: true])
                step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', projectId: env.PROJECT_ID, clusterName: env.CLUSTER_NAME, location: env.LOCATION, manifestPattern: 'deployment.yaml', credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID, verifyDeployments: true])
            }
```

Any help is highly appreciated as this is the first time we started implementing CI/CD.

Comment: You didn't specify what version of the plugin you're using, nor whether you're actually deploying to GKE or just squatting on their plugin, but setting aside those assumptions, it seems unable to [apply the metrics labels](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-kubernetes-engine-plugin/blob/google-kubernetes-engine-0.8.1/src/main/java/com/google/jenkins/plugins/k8sengine/KubernetesEngineBuilder.java#L303); your best bet is to [work with their GitHub issues](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-kubernetes-engine-plugin/issues?q=is%3Aissue+NullPointerException) since they have NPE problems it seems

Comment: Thanks for your response, @mdaniel plugin version is 0.8.1 and we actually are deploying docker app to gke.

Comment: 0.8.1 does not exist (and would be years old)
Looks like you are using the `google-kubernetes-engine-plugin` https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-kubernetes-engine-plugin

Comment: yes, I was using google kubernetes plugin, I made the correction in the question, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you solved this. I ran into this problem before, check your YAML file.

I left one `---` at the end of my YAML file which causes Jenkins this type of error. Removing the last `---` cleared the error.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...

---

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...

---  # <-- remove it
```

**Note: when you do standalone "kubectl apply ...", the trailing `---` will be ignored**

Comment: I came across this today, thanks for this.